# how to develop a api ai with node-js web application?

Tags: node.js, web-applications, google-api-nodejs-client, api-ai

I am trying to develop a simple web application for food menu, for this user request as natural language, the response should fetch from api ai and display it.

Comment: should we build the api for you then? do some research...

Comment: @PaoloMangia they are asking about `api.ai`. Although the question is a bit broad.